# Ubuntu Server 18.04 - Can’t ping to server from another computer

Tags: networking, server, vmware, firewall, ping

I made a VMWare virtual machine on an old laptop I am currently using as a server. I set up Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, set up OpenSSH, and UFW. I can ping to my computer and to my router, however, when I want to ping to the server using my computer, it has no response, I pinged with the localhost IP address, and I thought I could just ssh with the local IP address, but it didn't work.

I've read through the same articles that are going through the same problem as I, and they all point to Firewall settings, now the question is how do I allow my Firewall to ping, and ssh access to my server from another computer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What network settings have you configured in vmware?

Comment: I have network settings configured to NAT, but I am testing the other option which is Bridged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the network type to bridged.

When you configure your network type in VMWare Workstation to NAT, it NAT's traffic using the host computers IP. That works fine if you only want to access the network from the virtual machine, but it makes access to the virtual machine from other computers difficult.

Bridged, however, will let the VM connect directly to your network, and receive an IP from the DHCP server of the network. This is what you want if you want it to be accessible from your network.

Comment: You were correct, I figured it out minutes before you answered it, was gonna edit my question with a solution of my own, but your solution is more specific and clearer. Thanks for the help. Now to set up the server on an actual computer.